# Function returning an object by value or nothing if object doesn't exists

Tags: c++, qt, containers

What would be the best signature of a function returning a class object by value or something special if object does not exists?

For function returning more than one object, function prototype is

```
QList<X> getSomeXOrNothing();
```

- it returns list of objects if there are objects, or empty list if there is no objects, which fully suits my needs and is convenient to work with.

Now, I know that function can only return single object or nothing, what would be the best signature? Returning a raw pointer is not desirable since it has potential for error leaks.

I'm debating between returning shared pointer or still returning a list with a single value:

```
QList<X> getSingleXOrNothing(); 
QSharedPointer<X> getSingleXOrNothing();
```

but I am wondering if there are any better ways to do that - shared pointer adds unnecessary overhead, while returning a list is controversial since I know list can contain only one object.

**EDIT:**
All of QList, SharedPointr and QVariant are acceptable options, but I'm developing for embedded device where every byte counts, and there will be a lot of calls to this function - so trying to find optimal container given conditions - it is one object or nothing.

Comment: what overhead are you talking about? a shared_ptr is the WTG, trust your compiler's optimization.

Comment: What is your X? If it's one of the types that QVariant supports, then you could use that.

Comment: Given that QSharedPointer returns a pointer to the object, how about just returning a pointer or NULL?

Comment: Maybe I missed something, but whats wrong with just returning an empty list ? yeah, I know its an overhead thing, but *really* ?

Comment: @peppe - Returning a pointer requires caller to explicitly delete it if object can be created (we will need to create it on heap), and is prone to memory leaks.

Comment: @WhozCraig - all of QLsit, SharedPointr and QVariant are acceptable options, but I'm developing for embedded device where every byte counts, and there will be a lot of calls to htis function - so trying to find optimal container given conditions - it is one object or nothing.

Comment: @IlyaKobelevskiy: sure, let's return a `unique_ptr` instead...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the "Option Pattern".  The basic idea is:

```
template <typename T>
class Optional {
    private:
        bool valueIsPresent;
        T value;
}
```

Then, from the function you can return `Optional<YourType>`.  Client code can then check if a value is effectively present before trying to access it and use it.

Comment: Thanks, that might work - essentially, I'm looking for some templated storage with minimal overhead! Do you know if there is anything like that implemented for Qt?

Comment: @IlyaKobelevskiy I'm not sure about Qt but boost has [boost::optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html). (PS. Wouldn't Optional as defined here construct value anyway using constructor with no parameters?)

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka  I was thinking of primitive types and making pointer  types explicit.  Depends on expected semantics.

Comment: @IlyaKobelevskiy  Not that I know of.  If you are not using `boost`, it could be a good opportunity to start using it.  Producing a complete implementation of the pattern **again** doesn't make any sense.  And using an incomplete one can bring you more problems than benefits.

Comment: Interestingly enough, C++14 will have [std::optional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it in C++ but it might be a fun idea to try - why not use continuation style ('Church encoding'), especially if your compiler supports tail call optimization and C++11 (probably not given it is embedded but it might be fun to check)?

```
template<typename One, typename Zero, typename X>
X getSomeOrZero (One one, Zero zero) {
    if (logic)
        return one (X ());
    else
        return zero ();
}

void process () {
    auto x = getSome ([] (one) => { handle one }, [] () => { handle zero });
}
```

For more conservative (correct?) approach see Mario answer.

Comment: +1, interesting approach! I think I will go with Mario Rossi answer since it is minimalistic approach I need and unfortunately there is no C++11 on embedded, but your idea definitely worth checking it, thanks :)

Comment: @IlyaKobelevskiy Strictly you don't need C++11 as it was used just for lambdas (in C++03 you'd create a functors). In any case I don't have experience with such style in C++ so I'd go with Mario's answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Throw an exception if the object does not exist.

Simplest and safest way to do it.

Plus does not require extra overhead of a bool value to check if the Object exists.

Comment: a) Exceptions are very costly when they are thrown so there is an overhead. Normally for the uncommon case but here for the common one. b) Exceptions are not semantically correct here and c) (personal opinion) unchecked exceptions are bad - you never know when one is thrown and you terminated the function with inconsistent state (RAII helps in some cases but not with, for example, middle of adding something to structure).

Comment: Sure. I didn't know about he cost of exceptions but for point c) the code calling getSomeXorNothing() would have to check that the returned object was valid anyway and then cancel/change adding to structure which would be no different to using a try catch block

Answer (score 0):

Qt itself often uses an `isValid()` or `isNull()` method.
If you add an `isValid` member to your class, and in the default constructor initialize that member to `false`, then you have a neat solution.